# Click on ListView

Tags: android, listview, onclick

my question is simple. When i click on an item in a ListView, the background changes to green. I use that ListView only to show item, not to interact. I do not want this behavior. Is it possible?

---

Edit:
Sorry for my bad english. I want the ListView to be 'non-clickable'. When you put your finger on a item, by default that item is highlighted. When you put your finger away that item returns normal. I do not want this behavior. I want to use that ListView only to show items. When a user put his finger on that item, i want it not to be highlighted. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you possible clarify what you're asking a little more?

Comment: Post your code. It could be the click handler is on the wrong view or something else but I can't say with seeing your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In code:

```
setClickable(false);
```

or in XML:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: Beat me to it +1. I also call `setLongClickable(false)`.